# "Message Queue service is not available" when service automatically starts after reboot

Tags: nservicebus

The services terminate due to MSMQ not being started at the time they're trying to start up, so the obvious solution would be to set the startup type to automatic (delayed). Rather than going with the obvious solution I'm wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong?

I'm using NServiceBus V5 on Win2012 and started to get these messages on all my installed services after I upgraded to V5 from V4. They're installed to start automatically when the server boots up. This hasn't happened before, and the services start normally if I manually start them.

Comment: Check that they are depending on the msmq service?

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund They're not depending on MSMQ. I'm using the nservicebus.host.exe, and installing with basic switches like servicename. Looking through the documentation it looks like i can add a dependency via a switch. but i'm not sure what I should plug in for the value to make it depend on msmq, but that looks like it should be the solution. Would you mind posting an answer with the details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the NServicebus is running in NServiceBus.Host.exe, in order to get the service to start after MSMQ, there's a switch that needs to be used when installing the service (I used one line, broke it into multiple lines for readability):

```
.\NServiceBus.Host.exe /install
/servicename:"service"
/displayname:"display"
/dependsOn:"MSMQ"
```

I had tried "Message Queing" since that's what was in the service control manager, but I guess it doesn't take the display name. I found that MSMQ was the service name by right clicking on the service and viewing the service name field at the top.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong--I think it's what you suspect: your service is starting up before the Message Queuing Service is ready.

Comment: @ton.yeung It can also be useful to set service dependency between message infrastructure service an your service.

Answer (score 1):

You can set service dependencies without having to reinstall.

use the following command: **sc config YOURSERVICENAME depend=MSMQ**